# Determine the singular part of $f$ at these poles.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Show that $f(z)=\tan(z)$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ excpet for simple poles at $z=(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Determine the singular part of $f$ at these poles.

My thought is to consider the power series for both $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ and since those are entire deal with what happens at the poles. I'm not really sure about the singular part here because I have two general power series and there doesn't seem to be a good way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution. We can argue about it.

**Proof:** We know that $\tan (z)=\frac {\sin z}{\cos z}$ and that $\sin z$,$\cos z$ are analytics in $\mathbb{C}$. Then, $\tan z$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ except at points where $\cos z$ vanishes. Note that the poles of $f$ are exatly the zeros of $\cos z$. Take $z_n=\pi/2+n\pi \mbox{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. See that exist a $g:G\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic in $G$ such that $$f(z)=\frac {g(z)}{(z-z_n)^m}\Rightarrow g(z)=f(z)(z-z_n)^m,$$
and, the small integer m such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_n}f(z)(z-z_n)^m$ exist is $m=1$. So, the pole of $f$ is simple $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now we can get
$$g(z)=\frac {\sin z}{\cos z}(z-z_n)=\sin z \frac{(z-z_n)}{\cos z}\longrightarrow-1,$$
with ${z\rightarrow z_n}$. Then $f(z)=\frac {-1}{(z-z_n)}+g_1(z)$ with $g_1$ analytic. Then part singular of $f$ is $\frac {-1}{(z-z_n)}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
$\blacksquare$